# I have three brothers

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> The number of brothers I have is three
>   Though they each deny knowing me
>   Each of them I can swiftly defeat
>   Yet they do not accept they're beat
>   For each shall claim at last
>   "Cheated, thou hast"

---

Do you see?
What might I be?

Comment: Was this too easy?

Comment: @can-ned_food I guess so. Sorry.

Comment: Well, no, I must apologize:  rhyming riddles are to Puzzling SE as Minecraft questions are to Arqade SE.  It is often too tempting to hide a simple interpretation behind a multitude of lines.  IMHO, a riddle either uses rhyming as a gimmick or as a handicap to increase the challenge for the riddler; the better ones can also use rhyming as a ruse — or even as a way to include a bit of wordplay and linguistic and phonetic fun.  As to what constitutes a good riddle — there are a few Meta Puzzling questions on various facets of that.

Comment: It's not a bad riddle, but there aren't many possible solutions which almost seem to fit but which conflict with one or two conditions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Loooong shot ...

> You're a finger gun in a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors - because guns beat everything.

*The number of brothers I have is three*

> The brothers are Rock, Paper, Scissors.

*Though they each deny knowing me*

> But they don't accept the finger gun as a valid fourth brother.

*Each of them I can swiftly defeat*

> A gun beats everything.

*Yet they do not accept they're beat*
*For each shall claim at last*
*"Cheated, thou hast"*

> Well, yeah - it totally is cheating, and not valid according to the standard rules of the game.

On a less cheaty note, you could be

> the trumps suit in a card game. That suit beats all the others ... but I'm not sure where the cheating, or non-acceptance by the others of your victory, would come in there,

Comment: I think you have the reasoning correct, but not the actual answer. I would link to the "controversy" that I think this question references, but it'd be a spoiler.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor    Seems like if he has 3 brothers then there would be 4 brothers total...doesn't seem to support the 'rock, paper, scissors' approach where there are a total of 3?

Comment: Gun is correct, along with all of your reasoning!

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Whaaaaaaat? I posted this only semi-seriously, hesitating to do so at all, and half-expected it to get downvoted into the basement. Not in my wildest dreams did I imagine +28 and an accept :-OOO

Comment: @Randal'Thor lol it is what I intended though

Comment: Where does "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock" fit in?

Comment: @DrXorile why does it need to?